# VBA code for converting feet to decimal

Tags: vba

Can anyone provide the VBA codes for below

```
Shutter inside drawer   2'9"x2'     5.5
Niche                   5'4"x1'2"   6.218
Door                    6'1"x2'6"   15.207
```

Comment: I assume you want to convert from imperial to metric. Convert the dimensions to inch then convert inch to metric.  6.1 for door is to low :)

Answer (score 0):

Below is the vba code for reading value in feet and inches and returning the area. It's been written under the assumption that the length and breadth in feet and inches of each of the items are provided in separate cells. It can be optimized if the input is in a different format. Hope this helps.

```
Sub sCalcArea()

Shutter_inside_drawer_1_feet = Cells(2, 1)
Shutter_inside_drawer_1_inch = Cells(2, 2)
Shutter_inside_drawer_2_feet = Cells(2, 3)
Shutter_inside_drawer_2_inch = Cells(2, 4)

Shutter_Inside_Drawer_Area = (Shutter_inside_drawer_1_feet + Shutter_inside_drawer_1_inch / 12) * (Shutter_inside_drawer_2_feet + Shutter_inside_drawer_2_inch / 12)
Cells(2, 5) = Shutter_Inside_Drawer_Area


Niche_1_feet = Cells(3, 1)
Niche_1_inch = Cells(3, 2)
Niche_2_feet = Cells(3, 3)
Niche_2_inch = Cells(3, 4)

Niche_Area = (Niche_1_feet + Niche_1_inch / 12) * (Niche_2_feet + Niche_2_inch / 12)
Cells(3, 5) = Niche_Area


Door_1_feet = Cells(4, 1)
Door_1_inch = Cells(4, 2)
Door_2_feet = Cells(4, 3)
Door_2_inch = Cells(4, 4)

Door_Area = (Door_1_feet + Door_1_inch / 12) * (Door_2_feet + Door_2_inch / 12)
Cells(4, 5) = Door_Area

End Sub
```